# insert total ammount of selected checkbox values in db

Tags: php, mysql, database, checkbox, foreach

I'm  quite new to PHP, and have been trying to store the total ammount of checkbox values in the database, but for some reason (probably lack of logic). It doesn't work:

```
<?php
        mysql_connect( 'localhost',  'root', '')or die("cannot connect");
        mysql_select_db('webgame')or die("cannot select DB");

        $perms = array(
                    'writePost' => 1,
                    'readPost' => 2,
                    'deletePost' => 4,
                    'addUser' => 8,
                    'deleteUser' => 16,
        );



        echo "<form method='post' action='v3.php'>";
        foreach($perms as $key => $value)
        {
            echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$value."'>\n";
            echo "<label for='".$key."'>".ucfirst($key)."</label><br>\n";
        }
            echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
            echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $total = 0; 

            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) 
            {
                if( isset($perms[ $value ]) )
                    $total += $perms[ $value ]; 
            }



            mysql_query("INSERT INTO perms (name, rights) VALUES(name, $total)") or die(mysql_error());
        }




    ?>
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your checkbox markup like this:

```
 foreach($perms as $key => $value)
    {
       echo "<input type='checkbox' value='".$value."' name='checkbox[]'>\n";
        echo "<label for='".$key."'>".ucfirst($key)."</label><br>\n";
    }
```

And then to access it like this:

```
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $total = 0; 

        foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $checkbox) 
        {
                $total += $checkbox; 

        }


        echo $total;
        mysql_query("INSERT INTO perms (name, rights) VALUES(name, $total)") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: sum the values of all the checked checkboxes, do you know how that is been done?

Comment: get these errors:  Undefined index: checkboxes line 27 and Invalid argument supplied for foreach() also line 27

Comment: are you sure you're using the code from the answer above? I have suggested "checkbox" rather than "checkboxes" as the variable names and the index in $_POST. Basically you have to make sure that whatever you use as the name for your form elements matches what you later use to retrieve it within the $_POST['']

Answer (score 0):

I see a few issues. Some will cause more issues than others.

(1) You are missing the `name` attribute in your checkboxes. (2) You are missing the closing `</form>` tag. (3) Your Query is probably failing as you have `VALUES(name, $total)`, and I assume `name` is a string so it needs to be in quotes `VALUES('name', $total)`, or more likely `VALUES('$name', $total)`

Also, I don't see why you are connecting to your database on the initial page load. I would move that inside your `isset($_POST['submit'])`.

Try this -

```
<?php
    $perms = array(
                'writePost' => 1,
                'readPost' => 2,
                'deletePost' => 4,
                'addUser' => 8,
                'deleteUser' => 16,
    );

    echo "<form method='post' action='v3.php'>";
    foreach($perms as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes[]' value='".$value."'>\n";  
        echo "<label for='".$key."'>".ucfirst($key)."</label><br>\n";
    }
        echo "<input type='text' name='name'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='submit'>";
        echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
       mysql_connect( 'localhost',  'root', '')or die("cannot connect");
       mysql_select_db('webgame')or die("cannot select DB");

        $total = 0; 
        $name  = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
        foreach ($_POST['checkboxes'] as $keys=>$vals)
        {
                $total += $vals;
        }

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO perms (name, rights) VALUES('$name', $total)") or die(mysql_error()); 
   }
?>
```

Also, the `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API guide](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) and [related FAQ](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.